# Show One WindowInfo Per Marker(Google Map)

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I try this but I can only last windowInfo.
Help me please

```js
function initialize() {
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.414837,54.68141),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),mapOptions);
/*var weatherLayer = new google.maps.weather.WeatherLayer({
    temperatureUnits: google.maps.weather.TemperatureUnit.Degree
});
weatherLayer.setMap(map);*/
/*var cloudLayer = new google.maps.weather.CloudLayer();
cloudLayer.setMap(map)*/
for (i = 0; i < StationListArray.length; i++) {
    var image = StationListArray[i].split("|")[4];
    var StationLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(StationListArray[i].split("|")[2], StationListArray[i].split("|")[1]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: StationLocation,
        map: map,
        title: StationListArray[i].split("|")[0],
        icon: image
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function() {
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content:"Hello World!"});
    infowindow.open(map,marker); 
    });

} 
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Improve the formatting of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Change the 2nd argument of open() to `this`

```
infowindow.open(map,this);
```

`marker` refers to the `variable` marker, which will be overwritten on each iteration. When the loop has been finished, it points to the last marker that has been created. `this` inside the `click`-callback refers to the marker that has been clicked.